# should one invert syntax for the verb "do" in a comparison?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subject-verb-inversion

Which sounds better:

When Canadians do initiate conversations, they tend to be more reserved than Americans do.

When Canadians do initiate conversations, they tend to be more reserved than do Americans.

Comment: The second *do*, wherever you put it, should be *are*. And why not leave it out altogether?

Comment: OK well use a different example then. "The report demonstrated that Canadians are more likely to be denied entry than are Americans." You wouldn't want to elide the "are" in this case, because "The report demonstrated that Canadians are more likely to be denied entry than Americans" sounds awkward. So which sounds better? "The report demonstrated that Canadians are more likely to be denied entry than are Americans" or "The report demonstrated that Canadians are more likely to be denied entry than Americans are"?

Comment: No, either of the examples is fine, and so is leaving it out altogether.

Comment: I don't see any reason why it has to be *are* rather than *do*. These aren't easy constructions for me to find examples of, but [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22tend+to+be+slower+than+do%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are a couple of instances of *"tend to be slower than do"*. They look fine to me, and the same text replacing *do* with *are* finds no hits.

Comment: *"I am reserved, and so **are** you."* But *"I tend to be reserved, and so **do** you."* With the OP's sentence structure, I think it should be ***than do Americans***, but ***than Americans are*** or ***than Americans do*** both work.

Comment: Are you asking for literate use, or pedestrian street-talk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I'm going to remove the first *do* in each statement, and come back to it later.

> When Canadians initiate conversations, they tend to be more reserved than Americans do.
>
> When Canadians initiate conversations, they tend to be more reserved than do Americans.

Both read fine, but which is stronger? There's an interesting thing happening in the second, which we can see if we rewrite them to not use do-support:

> When Canadians initiate conversations, they tend to be more reserved than Americans tend to be.

We can't actually do that with the other one and come out with the same meaning, the closest I can get is:

> When Canadians initiate conversations, they tend to be more reserved than is the tendency of Americans.

Which is more than a simple, direct rewrite. Indeed, it's quite different, indeed.

The interesting thing about the second of the first sentences, is that we have the verb before the subject. Much of the time, this plain won't work in English. Some of the time, it'll be understandable, but sound pretty weird, or match some archaic constructions.

Here though it's a mild, but very pleasing example of *hyperbaton*, and it leads to the sentence ending on one of the groups we are interested in, rather than the relatively weak *do*. (The reason it's mild, is that verb-subject is nowhere near as rare with *do*, *be*, *have* and a few other verbs as it is with most, so it's arguably not really hyperbaton at all).

Now, let's consider StoneyB's suggestion from the comments, but again with my edit:

> When Canadians initiate conversations, they tend to be more reserved than Americans are.
>
> When Canadians initiate conversations, they tend to be more reserved than are Americans.

Okay, here rather than using *do* to match the earlier verb phrase, we use *are* to match the *to be* in that earlier phrase, and hence evoke it.

And it pretty much matches, as far as that mild hyperbaton goes. Again, I prefer the second.

I still prefer the *do* form to the *are* form. Partly, at least, this is because it could be seen as matching how reserved Canadians tend to be in a given situations, with how reserved Americans are generally. It's one of those mild ambiguities where I wouldn't actually misinterpret it that way, but it does weaken the impact. (We could also leave out the *are* and have "...tend to be more reserved than Americans", but that has the same issue even more strongly).

Okay, now to go back to having the first *do* in there:

> When Canadians do initiate conversations, they tend to be more reserved than do Americans.

When I first read the two sentences, they seemed wrong to me, and the reason was that I was matching the *do* at the end to the *do* near the beginning. Now, that was a misreading, and when I read them again more carefully, I realised the meaning. Still, even now it reads to me like that repetition—even of such a weak word as *do* can be—is deliberate and meaningful, and I trip over it mentally. (Incidentally, I found that effect even worse with the other sentence suggested).

Now, presumably that *do* is there for a good reason. At a guess, an earlier statement is saying that Canadians don't often initiate conversations, with this sentence addressing the exception to that. It's a good reason to have *do* in there; the last thing you want is the reader to react with "why are you talking about Canadians initiating conversations, you just said they don't!"

But I do still find that repetition to be a bit of a burr.

So, **if** you can remove that *do* without causing problems in the wider context, I would recommend:

> When Canadians initiate conversations, they tend to be more reserved than do Americans.

If however that seems contradictory in the context, I'd recommend:

> When Canadians do initiate conversations, they tend to be more reserved than are Americans.

Again though, this is offering an opinion of effect, which is subjective.

The more general answer to the more general question, "Should one invert syntax for the verb “do” in a comparison?" is that you can, but you don't have to, and while I may favour it in this case, others may disagree, and I may disagree myself with another example. "So baby talk to me, Like do lovers" just wouldn't work as well as "So baby talk to me, Like lovers do".

Comment: +1 for making the important point (which I failed to explicitly identify) that the sentence is stronger/better/clearer if it ends with the "operative" word *Americans*, rather than just a grammatically-prompted auxiliary like *do* or *are*. Don't take this the wrong way, but I'm not going to delete my answer as promised, because I think given the length of this one, there should be a shorter alternative (if only as a TL;DR! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers No wrong way to take it, you answered first and you answered well, so you should only delete it if you think you're wrong (in which case I'd disagree with your thinking that).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I do think that the fact that verb-then-subject is unusual in English is another reason for the strength. It's not quite hyperbaton, but it's something akin to it.

Comment: If by that you mean *than do Americans* is inherently "stronger" than *than Americans do* even disregarding whether the sentence actually *ends* there, then yes - I agree. On the other point, I don't really think I answered that well, since I failed to adequately justify my preference (but you've now picked out at least two reasons). Anyway, I have the sneaking suspicion that if John Lawler were to turn his attention to this one, my contribution would fade into insignificance!

Answer (score 3):

I am hesitant to write this because I am new here and others on this site are far far more knowledgeable than I. That said, and assuming the first *do* is for contrasting with a previous statement, I would go for

> When Canadians do initiate conversations, they tend to be more reserved than Americans.

The meaning here is that when Canadians, who do not often do so, initiate a conversation they are more reserved than Americans in the same situation. I do not understand the need for a final verb. Like the Canadians, the fictitious Americans in question are also initiating a conversation. They are not *doing* and they aren't *being* anything. Both the final *are* and the final *do* seem unnecessary.

Granted that this form makes the sentence slightly more ambiguous. It could now be taken to mean that Canadians, when initiating a conversation, are more reserved than Americans *in general* as opposed to Americans initiating a conversation. Nevertheless, I feel that this form is clearer, easier to read and more natural.

Answer (score 1):

I'll delete this if anyone comes up with a better answer, but I think both versions are grammatically fine. You could replace *do* with *are*, but I see no reason that should be *required*.

As to *which sounds better?*, I prefer the second. It sounds more measured and formal, which is in keeping with the rest of the sentence. Sticking the auxiliary verb *do* (or *are*) at the end sounds more like a spoken form where the speaker hadn't quite thought out how he was going to finish until he got there (and arguably would have been better off not saying the last word at all).

---

EDIT: As has been pointed out, you don't *need* to use *"do"* at all. It would be pedantic to suppose the sentence was defective because of any potential ambiguity (i.e. - that Canadians when they happen to be initiating conversations are more reserved than Americans in general). But that's not what the question asks.

I also acknowledge Jon's point that the *reason* OP's second version is "better" is that *Americans* is the operative word in the clause, and as such has more impact in the final position.

Comment: Well, I had the same conclusion. I've a theory as to why, and also why StoneyB preferred *are* over *do*, so I just wrote that up a bit. +1 from me on yours, still.