# "than do I" vs. "than I do"

Tags: comparatives, subject-verb-inversion, do-support

I need grammatical explanations for the following two sentence structures:

> 1. *The mistakes children make in learning to speak tell linguists more about how children learn language **than do** the correct forms they use.*
> 2. *Freedman's survey showed that people living in small towns and rural areas consider themselves no happier **than do** people living in big cities.*

If noticed, would someone explain me why "do" appears after "than" in the both of the sentences above?

So, would it be correct if I say, "You explain it more clearly than do I"?

Comment: First, I see exactly as many instances of *do* as I see of *than*. Second,  You have not asked a real question by saying “you need grammatical explanations”. Third, these *do*-inversion questions have already been answered many a time before.

Comment: Also related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101993/should-one-invert-syntax-for-the-verb-do-in-a-comparison

Answer (score 1):

@tchrist is right. The sentence "You explain it more clearly than do I" is correct. The inversion in this case is used to express emphasis or indicate surprise.

Comment: Wrong: both are perfectly correct.

Comment: tchrist, did you mean to say that both "You explain it more clearly than do I" and "You explain it more clearly than I do" are correct?

Comment: Not only are they both correct, the "...than I do" is **far** more likely.