# What is the grammatical role of "do" in "Ty and Chris care more about Arsene Wenger than they *do* Arsenal"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, syntactic-analysis

In the following sentence,

> Ty and Chris **care** more **about** Arsene Wenger than they **do** Arsenal.

What is the proper name for the role of the verb **do** here in the context of grammar?

For example, the role of **they** in this sentence is *pronoun* since it replaces the phrase **Ty and Chris** to avoid duplication. The same goes for **do** which replaces the phrase **care about**, but **do** is a verb so it is definitely not a pronoun. What is the correct name of it?

Comment: I would say "than they do ***about*** Arsenal" but I don't know if the way you put it is incorrect. It doesn't sound good to me though

Comment: @sumelic The sentence comes from a native English speaker in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcbykRVcn7Y) at around 56 seconds. But even if you are right, the role of **do** should be the same with or without the **about**.

Comment: I suppose so. Maybe the answers to the following question will be helpful: [should one invert syntax for the verb “do” in a comparison?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101993) It's not the same question, but it seems to be about the same construction

Comment: @sumelic Thank you. It seems someone in that question calls it **auxiliary verb**, would you say it also applies to the **do** in the sentence of my question?

Comment: @cr001 a rather offtopic and a personal comment : But you can hardly expect Ty and Chris to be linguistically correct after brutal 5-1. #WengerOut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Do" is one of the English auxiliaries like "is" or "will". English auxiliaries are characterized by the "NICE" grammatical properties, which are described by this series of [slides by Geoff Pullum](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/grammar/aux_sli.pdf).

- N: special negation syntax/negative forms (do not, don't)
- I: can take Initial position in Interrogatives
- C: **"Code" interpretation of Complement ellipsis** (your example shows ellipsis)
- E: special emphasized forms when stressed

Auxiliaries are usually classified as "verbs" and therefore called 
"auxiliary verbs", although [I've heard from Greg Lee](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253185/why-can-i-contract-across-a-word-skipping-the-word-in-the-middle/253198#comment552830_253198) that there are some theories of syntax that treat them as not being verbs.

Comment: Is there really VP ellipsis here though? Are the gaps there because of the comparative clause? "Bob ate more melons than Maria oranges"

Comment: @Araucaria: I don't know the technical definition of ellipsis. Wikipedia seems to categorize comparatives as an example of [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)#Comparative_deletion)

Comment: I think your intuitions are right there. What I was angling at, I think, is whether this is really "code" in the same way. (shrugs)